# "cannot process or access the db_dump.sql file."

Tags: sql, cpanel, dpan

[Help me fix this issue "cannot process or access the db_dump.sql file."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v9aD.jpg)

Error I can't proceed to install the script because the script said cannot process or access the db_dump.sql file.
Please help me how to fix it thank u and have a nice day